# Spring Boot + WEB-INF

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jboss

I have a very simple spring boot project with   dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

When I build this , web-inf folder gets created in target directory, and packages everything in classes, and lib folder.

I want to have one xml file ("jboss-deployment-structure.xml") at the root of the web-inf, ("web-inf/jboss-deployment-structure.xml") where should I put it in the src folder?

I tried creating "public/jboss-deployment-structure.xml" folder in src, but no luck.

Answer (score 17):

Maybe a little bit late, but in order to put your xml file inside WEB-INF, if you are using Maven, the correct placement will be:

```
src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jboss-deployment-structure.xml
```

Answer (score 2):

For a regular maven project if you need to have a structure of

```
target/WEB-INF/blabla.xml
```

then you should put

```
src/main/resources/WEB-INF/blabla.xml
```

I hope that will help.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem working with the Spring boot projects.

This kind of project usually comes with embedded modules like Apache tomcat and prepared for use Spring annotations.

For change configurations and make your web application easily configurable I suggest to create from scratch. See this url for more information:

http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/

In my case I changed to:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

and I create my own structure.

Comment: does that mean, that dont use spring boot? just go with plain old spring mvc. as any ways, if we see sping boot starter pom, they use the same dependencies